# DateTime Between DateTime Range in Separate DataFrames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, between

### *Edited for clarity

I need to find values from ['DateA'], ['DateB'], etc. between a range of dates ['Start']['End'] and return a running count to ['A']['B'], etc., for every time ['DateA]', ['DateB'], etc. falls within the ['Start']['End'] range.

The start datetime and end datetime are overlapping 53-week increments. If any of the dates (A, B, C, or D) are within the 53-week window, the script will count those datetimes and return an integer. To add to the confusion, DateD will only return an integer if the datetime coincides with a value of "Failed" from the Pass_Fail element. As example:

#### Expected Output:

```
Start       End         A   B   C   D
10/30/19    11/04/20    0   0   4   3   
11/06/19    11/11/20    1   0   3   3
11/13/19    11/18/20    1   0   3   3
```

#### Dates DataFrame (simplified)

- the coinciding fail dates below are 02/13/20, 06/21/20, 07/15/20 (hence int "3" in col D of Expected Output above.

```
    DateA       DateB   DateC       DateD       Pass_Fail
0   11/07/20    None    06/21/20    02/09/20    Pass
1   None        None    06/11/20    12/14/19    Pass
2   None        None    09/21/19    03/26/20    Pass
3   None        None    03/20/20    02/13/20    Fail
4   None        None    08/16/20    06/21/20    Fail
5   None        None    None        01/06/20    Pass
6   None        None    None        04/03/20    Pass
7   None        None    None        07/15/20    Fail
8   None        None    None        02/20/20    Pass
9   None        None    None        03/22/20    Pass
10  None        None    None        11/15/19    Pass
```

I'm certain this is simple, but I'm obviously just starting out and couldn't locate a direct answer/problem-solve this myself.

Many thanks!
-DD

Comment: May you show the expected output?

Comment: Are you're saying that `A`, `B`, `C` extra are dates that you're pulling (so each column is a pulled date)? If so, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every time this date falls within this range". Wouldn't any date fall (or not fall) into a given range once?